# iframe scaling overlaps a button

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to include Amazon Review iframe , and it doesn't fit the mobile screen view. So I am using scale to scale the contents. This is the code:

```
<div class="wrap"> 
  <iframe class="frame" src=""></iframe>
</div>
<style>
.wrap {
    width: 320px;
    height: 192px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.frame {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 786px;
    border: 0;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
    -o-transform: scale(0.25);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
    transform: scale(0.45);

    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
</style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiuDR.jpg)

^^^^But when I try to scale it , it overlaps a button which I have in the footer, as shown in the image.
Can anyone help to fix this issue.
PS: Src is left blank on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever think of just changing the height 
in the following code:

```
.frame {
width: 1280px;
height: 786px;
```

Optimization to mobile with HTML is actually pretty easy considering an entire page.
try this tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If you can include the URL from that image that would also help.
Can you let me know if this helps?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiuDR.jpg
I tried with the meta tag, still didn't worked